# open many activities with bitmaps recursively

Tags: android, bitmap

I got a problem with my app: In my app, every `activity` has several `ImageViews`, each `ImageView` has a  `bitmap` set to it.If open many `activities recursively`, **allocated memory will keeping increasing**, and finally **MemoryCache is full**, so I can't display any bitmap otherwise app will `crash`.

What can I do with the `ImageView` whose `activity` is stopped? Can I `recycle` its `bitmap`, and reload the bitmap after its activity resumed?

I'm using **Fresco** to handle  bitmap loading and cache.

Comment: In other words: *I'm getting OOMException when working with bitmaps, but I'm trying to be clever and didn't mention about this, as such question would be marked as duplicate*

Comment: @Syed Raza Mehdi
What I want to know is: what can I do with those bitmaps whose activity was stopped, for example activity A start activity B, now A is stopped and can't be seen. In this situation, Can I set null bitmap for A's ImageView and load bitmap if A is back.
I'm new to SO, sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle memory while using `Bitmap` objects is to use `LruCache` and store your `Bitmap` inside.
Once you do not need your `Bitmap` anymore, you can store to your cache and recycle it to free as much memory as you can. If it is stored into cache, you just have to get your image from your cache.

This is my class handeling my cache :

```
public class ImagesCache {
private  LruCache <String, Bitmap> imagesWarehouse;
private static ImagesCache cache;

public static ImagesCache getInstance() {
    if(cache == null)
        cache = new ImagesCache();
    return cache;
}

public void initializeCache() {
    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

    imagesWarehouse = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
        protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
            // The cache size will be measured in kilobytes rather than number of items.
            int bitmapByteCount = value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight();

            return bitmapByteCount / 1024;
        }};
}

public void addImageToWarehouse(String key, Bitmap value) {       
    if (imagesWarehouse != null && imagesWarehouse.get(key) == null)
        imagesWarehouse.put(key, value);
}

public Bitmap getImageFromWarehouse(String key) {
    if (key != null)
        return imagesWarehouse.get(key);
    else
        return null;
}

public void removeImageFromWarehouse(String key) {
    imagesWarehouse.remove(key);
}

public void clearCache() {
    if (imagesWarehouse != null)
        imagesWarehouse.evictAll();
}
```

}

Remember to initialise your cache when your app starts

```
cache.initializeCache()
```

and clear if when your app finishes

```
cache.clearCache()
```

Comment: I am using [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) to do this job.And my question is: what to do with those bitmaps whose activity is stopped(for example its activity start another activity)